# Некорректный вывод данных из ListView в EditText

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-edittext

При выводе данных из ListView в EditText выводится данное: Рисунок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно исправить?

Первый актив:

```
docList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                String selectedFromList = String.valueOf(docList.getItemAtPosition(position));
                intent.putExtra("_doc", selectedFromList);

                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Второй актив:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
            return;
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CUST) {
            docBox.setText(data.getStringExtra("_doc"));
}}
```

Comment: а в базе что лежит? какие данные?

Comment: Данные типа string. Которые водятся вручную, через приложение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы используете `CursorAdapter` или его наследник, то `getItemAtPosition` возвращает курсор, установленный на указанную позицию и вы должны взять данные из него, например:

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) docList.getItemAtPosition(position);
intent.putExtra("_doc", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbContract.COLUMN_NAME)));
```

***** `DbContract.COLUMN_NAME` - это константа, в которой вы храните имя нужной колонки

P.S. если на той стороне вам нужно больше данных, а тем более их нужно править - то лучше передать просто `id` выбранной строки, а в другой активности по этому `id` работать напрямую с БД